# In Java, how to assign the variable number=Integer.parseInt(args[0]) a value if no argument is passed?

Tags: java, variables, assign, parseint

I wrote this simple program, that takes a command line argument, converts it into int type, and prints integers starting from that number till infinity on console.

If i don't pass any argument, then my exception message is printed.

```
public class Infinity
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        try
        {
            n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println(n);
                n++;
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("A number was not entered.");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way that if i don't pass any argument, the program itself assigns a value to 'n'? Like this:

```
            n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            if(args[0]==NULL)
            {
                n=0;
            }
```

Comment: `if(args.length > 0) { n = args[0]; } else { n = default; }` check if args length is greater than 0. If so, assign value to whatever arg is. If not, use a default value

Comment: Check the length first, before trying to reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign value of `n` as `0` or any other value by default and use `if(args.length > 0) {` to check whether any arguments is given. Below is full example with comments:

```
public class Infinity {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /*
        Start by assigning your default value to n, here it is 0
        If valid argument is not given, your program runs 
        starting from this value
        */
        int n = 0;

        // If any arguments given, we try to parse it
        if(args.length > 0) {

            try {
                n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Argument" + args[0] + " must be an integer.");

                // Program ends
                System.exit(1);
            }

        }

        // All good, n is either default (0) or user entered value
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(n);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Users which are not so familiar with java, this program can be run by:

1. Saving it to `Infinity.java`
2. Compiling it with cmd or terminal by writing: `javac Infinity.java`
3. Executing it with: `java Infinity` or `java Infinity 1000` (or any other value)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the `args` array before attempting to access.

```
int n = 0;
if (args.length == 1)
{
    n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
}
```

You still likely need a try/catch block if you want to handle an argument being provided that is not a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the arg, then parse it if you do. Otherwise, use your default value.

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    n = // default value
}
else {
    n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is! You can check the length of `args[]` so that when its 0 i.e no arguments were passed, a default value is assigned. Here's the  simplest code:

```
public class Infinity
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
        if(args.length<1)
        {
             n=0; //or any other default value
        }
        else
        {
            n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }//can also add a case to check in case the no. of arguments exceeds 1.
         }
        catch(Exception e)
         {e.printStackTrace();}
         while(true)
            {
                System.out.println(n);
                n++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are not try catching parsing

Answer (score -2):

```
/**
 *
 * @author salathielgenese
 */
public class Loader
{

    /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Init «n» to «0» by default. Even if the conversion failed, you'll get you variable to 0
        // But if the conversion goes on, then the value will be updated to args[0]
        int n = 0;
        if (null != args && 0 < args.length)
        {
            try
            {
                n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Argument" + args[0] + " must be an integer.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        // The rest of your code
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Give more detail as to what you're saying. Also, I'm pretty sure `args` isn't null when you don't set arguments, or you would get a `NullPointerException` for trying to call `args.length` (unless you nessed the length check within the null check)

Comment: You didn't give an explination. Good answers usually have a code example AND a summary of how that code helps